# WordPress and Mailpoet CRON

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I have a WordPress with MailPoet.

Someone know if possible to schedule CRON task for Mailpoet ?

I have to send Newsletter every day (Monday to Friday at 5pm) only if there is a new content from specific categorie.

But i dont know how Mailpoet works. I would like to create a script php but i didnt find sometjing about CRON and MailPoet on Google ...

I have the last version and premium of MailPoet.

Thansk for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is on the Mailpoet website:

http://docs.mailpoet.com/article/47-configure-cron-job

> 2.4 Cron job commands to call MailPoet's Cron URL
>
> Below are a few examples of commands you can use.
>
> You'll only need to set up one on your server, so simply pick the one
>   which works on your server ( curl is safer):
>
> `curl --silent "http://www.yourwebsite.com/wp-cron.php?xxxx..." > /dev/null 2>&1`
>
> `wget --quiet "http://www.yourwebsite.com/wp-cron.php?xxxx..."`
>
> Don't forget to replace http://www.yourwebsite.com/wp-cron.php?xxxx... with your
>   own MailPoet's Cron URL.
>
> Some hosts may allow you to set up cron commands from their admin
>   interfaces. But, the commands wget, curl and lynx may not be
>   available, so if the cron doesn't seem to be running, get in touch
>   with your host and they should be able to help you out.

Comment: This is for mailpoet 2.0, i'm using mailpoet 3.0 no ? Where can i find my Cron URL ? Not avaible on 3.0